# No route found for "GET /test/information/1/name": Method Not Allowed (Allow: PUT)

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I m trying to update a field using "/test/item/1/name" through "PUT" method and i am getting the below error
"**No route found for "GET /test/item/1/name": Method Not Allowed (Allow: PUT)**"

the same routes will work if i change the method to "POST"

I have even tried adding "**Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();**" in app.php before request is handled (i.e before "$request = Request::createFromGlobals();" )
https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/165

My routing configurations

```
information_set_name:
  pattern:  /item/{id}/name
  defaults: { _controller: TestInformationBundle:Item:setName, _format: json }
  requirements: { _method: put, id: \d+ }
```

symfony version:"v2.2.1"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();` in the app_dev.php if you work in development mode (as I can see from your error message).

And you should use another way of constraint for your `_method` param:

```
information_set_name:
  pattern:  /item/{id}/name
  defaults: { _controller: TestInformationBundle:Item:setName, _format: json }
  requirements: { id: \d+ }
  methods:   [PUT]
```

See the article http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html

Comment: i have tried it adding the methods and requirement separately but the issue still persists. will it make a difference if i work on app.php by enabling the debug mode on?

Comment: no issue with the routes if i change the method from **PUT** to **POST**

Answer (score 1):

For everybody who has the same problem. 
Some times routing is properly, but if you has an error in your controller Symfony returning notice "No route found". It is not  true, just try to put return statement on the first line in your controller and then check what will happen.
You should get **"status 200 OK"**.